# Every step has already defined a uses or run key, but still receiving an error

Tags: github-actions

GitHub Action keeps telling me the following error: `every step must define a uses or run key` I think I set the uses or run for each step already. What's the problem?

```
name: cci-api cicd
on: [push,pull_request]
jobs: 
  ci-enviroment-setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: 
    - name: Checkout Repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with: 
        python-version: '3.x'
        architecture: 'x64'
    - name: Setup Poetry
    - run: |
        python -m pip install -U pip
        pip install poetry
        poetry install
    - name: Azure Login
    - uses: Azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - name: Azure key vault - Get DB Secrets
      uses: Azure/get-keyvault-secrets@v1
      with: 
        keyvault: kv-prt-us-dev
        secrets: prt-cet
```

Comment: I guess you only have to remove the dashes for the keywords `run` and `uses`.

Comment: You can't use the `-` symbol for `name`, `run` and `uses` fielda on the same step. Only one `-` for the whole step. Here for example you have it for multiple `name` and `run` fields for the same step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other pointed out, each step is required to have either `run` or `uses` key:

```
name: cci-api cicd
on: [push,pull_request]
jobs: 
  ci-enviroment-setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: 
    - name: Checkout Repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with: 
        python-version: '3.x'
        architecture: 'x64'
    - name: Setup Poetry
    # removed - in front of run key
      run: |
        python -m pip install -U pip
        pip install poetry
        poetry install
    - name: Azure Login
    # removed - in front of uses key
      uses: Azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - name: Azure key vault - Get DB Secrets
      uses: Azure/get-keyvault-secrets@v1
      with: 
        keyvault: kv-prt-us-dev
        secrets: prt-cet
```

Comment: I can't really tell what's the difference between your code and the code I put it there

Comment: @SLN I've added comments to make it more clear what is different.

Comment: In my case, there was a line that appeared blank but actually had several spaces and a CR.  Finding that line and deleting it which fixed the problem.